How to run a workflow in the text/markdown field in Rewst?
I was working in Rewst today and would like to display all of the results of a workflow in a text/markup. So far in my form the user selects the distribution list -> selects if they want to add/remove/view the users in the distro. When the user selects add or remove a workflow is triggered to get the appropriate users for the distro.
Ideally I would like to display the results of the workflow in the text/markdown field.
Here are my concerns:

I dont want to have the user click the users dropdown to view the users in the distro and scroll through them but from what I can tell a Rewst text/markdown field can not run a work flow(maybe set up a custom trigger?)

Any thoughts?
